# python manage.py runserver No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am a Python newbie and trying to configure Django on Mac OS X 10.9.4. I installed Django using the following command.

`$ pip install Django==1.6.6`

Now I started making the project.

`$ django-admin.py startproject test1`

Now I try to run the server by being in the directory of my new project. `$ python manage.py runserver`

But I get the following error. 
`python manage.py runserver Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 8, in <module> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ImportError: No module named django.core.management`

And my manage.py file looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test1.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

By going through all the references I got from StackOverflow, I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. 
What am I missing out here??

On running this code: 
`import sys
print sys.path`

I get the following output:

`['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg',` `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',` '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? Did you activate it before called `runserver`? (You might have installed Django on a different Python environment)

Comment: I didn't install any virtualenv as far as I know

Comment: just my experience. once i try to launch django in MS powershell and output exactly the same error as you have, but no if i did it in cmd, in virtualenv though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure django is on your python path?
Check your python path first.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. I could fix it as following.

Installing packages.

```
 (myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/test2$ pip list
    Django (1.6.11)
    django-dbindexer (1.6.1)
    django-mongodb-engine (0.6.0)
    djangotoolbox (1.8.0)
    pip (7.1.2)
    pymongo (3.0.3)
    setuptools (18.2)
    wheel (0.24.0)
```

Ubuntu terminal code

```
    umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ ls -l
total 0

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ virtualenv myprojec
New python executable in myprojec/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ source myprojec/bin/activate

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6
Collecting https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6

/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6
     | 6.7MB 1.9MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Django
  Stored in directory: /home/umayanga/.cache/pip/wheels/89/cd/89/64475e53eef52b22b711705322a36352f2f979fdcef0e39e8a
Successfully built Django
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django-1.6.11


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 6 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 myprojec

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ cd myprojec/
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 local
-rw-rw-r-- 1 umayanga umayanga   60 Oct 10 15:26 pip-selfcheck.json

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ (myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ cd ..

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install pymongo
Collecting pymongo

/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-3.0.3

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox to /tmp/pip-Lloitv-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-Lloitv-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox

  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangotoolbox==1.8.0 from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install django-dbindexer

Collecting django-dbindexer
/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading django-dbindexer-1.6.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: django-dbindexer
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-dbindexer
  Stored in directory: /home/umayanga/.cache/pip/wheels/09/2f/ea/01d26e4ffc98cd2ed54b92f31a82aecccb8e7b5c9e3b28a8ca
Successfully built django-dbindexer
Installing collected packages: django-dbindexer
Successfully installed django-dbindexer-1.6.1


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox

Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox to /tmp/pip-2AUZTq-build
Installing collected packages: djangotoolbox
  Running setup.py install for djangotoolbox
Successfully installed djangotoolbox-1.8.0

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine to /tmp/pip-63Fwrm-build
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo>=2.8 in ./myprojec/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangotoolbox>=1.6.0 in ./myprojec/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0)
Installing collected packages: django-mongodb-engine
  Running setup.py install for django-mongodb-engine
Successfully installed django-mongodb-engine-0.6.0

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ cd myprojec

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ django-admin.py startproject myproject
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 local
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:36 myproject
-rw-rw-r-- 1 umayanga umayanga   60 Oct 10 15:26 pip-selfcheck.json

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ (myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ cd myproject/

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxrwxr-x 1 umayanga umayanga  252 Oct 10 15:36 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:36 myproject
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
October 10, 2015 - 10:06:57
Django version 1.6.11, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[10/Oct/2015 10:07:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1757
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1757
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:48] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1865
```